# How can I break line the values called from a function

Tags: python

I am using Python 2 to make an app that counts the string words number and letters number.

```
def string_length(aStr):
    number_of_words = len(aStr.split())
    number_of_letters = len(aStr)
    return number_of_words, number_of_letters

print string_length("my name is ahmed") #Returns (4, 16)
```

How can I turn (4, 16) to:

4

16

Comment: Google it man, seriously.

Comment: I searched and I couldn't find any solution, is there any problem if someone helps me here?

Comment: Problem is this is an extremely trivial problem that you can find it on Google in 2 minutes.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with that `(4, 15)` tuple. You want to turn it into a 4 and a 16? Does that mean you want to store those two numbers in two different variables? Or are you trying to say that you want to _print_ 4 and 16 to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `string_length` function is returning a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), you have to *unpack* them before printing.

```
def string_length(aStr):
    number_of_words = len(aStr.split())
    number_of_letters = len(aStr)
    return number_of_words, number_of_letters

# Unpacking the tuple
words, letters = string_length('my name is ahmed')

print words
print letters
```

Answer (score 1):

call the function like

```
number_of_words, number_of_letters = string_length("Whatever string")
```

And then print the values

```
 print number_of_words
 print number_of_letters
```

Comment: Should my final code be:
`def string_length(aStr):
    number_of_words = len(aStr.split())
    number_of_letters = len(aStr)

number_of_words, number_of_letters = string_length("aStr")
print number_of_words
print number_of_letters`?